# What's the best way keep data of individual list of row values?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm very new to Swift as well as SwiftUI and recently started working on a MacOS app.

I have a dynamic list view of items that can be added or removed from the list (currentActionList) and it gets added when user selects a specific item from a dropdown list then it gets added to the list view.

My question is A(), B(), C() all have different things to keep track of (input field, count, dropdown list option selected... etc etc) then at the end when the list is complete I want to output array of all the row items.

Is having a struct format for A,B,C then saving it as @State the best idea?

Thank you!

```
@State public var currentActionList = [Int]()
@State public var rowItems = [SomeStructOfABC] // do this to keep list data?

List {
    if currentActionList.count > 0 {
        ForEach(currentActionList, id: \.self) { currentAction in
            if currentAction == 0 {
                A()
            } else if currentAction == 1 {
                B()
            } else if currentAction == 2 {
                C()
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're conflating two different things here. `ForEach` needs to output `View`s. So, you putting `A()` inside the `ForEach` suggests that `A()` is going to be a `View`. But, earlier, in `rowItems` it looks like maybe `A`, `B` and `C` represent your model? It's a little unclear.

Comment: In general, you want your model to be `struct`s, stored either in a `@State` variable, or, more likely, in a `@Published` property of an `ObservableObject` view model. Your child views may get a `@Binding` to these items to modify it inside the original array of items.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).